# Python in SPSS Create new variable run arcpy script

Tags: python, arcgis, spss, arcpy

I have just found this module, and need a bit of help moving my ArcGIS python script over to python/SPSS module.  The script uses the Updatecursor feature from the Arcpy module.  Here is my text so far.

```
# BEGIN PROGRAM.
import arcpy

fc = C:\Users\Desktop\file.TXT
fields =('RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS1', 'RESIDENTIAL_SECONDARY_ADDR', 'RESIDENTIAL_CITY', 'FULL_ADDRESS')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[3] = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    del cursor

# END PROGRAM.
```

I need the code to run on the current open file, create the new variable, do the concatenate.  I know I can do this through SPSS much easier, but I have many more additional python scripts I need to import in that do much more involved calcs also using the arcpy Update/Search Cursors.

My file size consists of 8 million records and came from a sqlexpress dbf. My python script was running in ArcGIS where I was doing some additional geocoding. I also run about another 5 to 6 python scripts doing various other calcs that I cannot program (like I can program concatenate) in spss. So my goal is to bring those python scripts into SPSS to do those calcs in SPSS instead of in ArcGIS. This was my first Arcpy task so I through it in here as an example of how to get this to work properly using the Python Plugin –

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an extended comment. I'm confused where `C:\Users\Desktop\file.TXT` comes into play - is that not your currently opened file? Consider using `spss.Submit` for such a simple task of concatenating fields within an active SPSS file (e.g. there is no need to iterate over every row in the data for this task). So here is a simple example:

```
DATA LIST FREE / Add1 Add2 (2A20) City (A6) State (A2).
BEGIN DATA
"125 Main St" "" Albany NY
"Main St." "Lake St" Albany NY
END DATA.

BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss
fields = ['Add1','Add2','City','State']
conc = ",' ',".join(fields)
spss.Submit("""
STRING ConcField (A255).
COMPUTE ConcField= CONCAT(%s).
""" % (conc))
END PROGRAM.
```

In unicode mode this will collapse the white space - but otherwise you would need to adjust your list to be something like `RTRIM(Add1)` for all of the different variables. This is just a simple example though.

SPSS has similar method to arcPy's cursor named `spss.Cursor`, but from your example it isn't clear that is what is necessary.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have added, my file size consists of 8 million records and came from a sqlexpress dbf.  My python script was running in ArcGIS where I was doing some additional geocoding.  I also run about another 5 to 6 python scripts doing various other calcs that I cannot program (like I can program concatenate) in spss.  So my goal is to bring those python scripts into SPSS to do those calcs in SPSS instead of in ArcGIS.  This was my first Arcpy task so I through it in here as an example of how to get this to work properly using the Python Plugin